# Where can I ask about (non-computer) game design? Particularly concerning educational games?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stackexchange site where I can ask questions concerning:

- Game design (non-computer games)
- Gamification (e.g. within educational games)
- References / studies which mechanisms make a game popular
- Basic rules to consider in game design

I was thinking (depending on the exact question) maybe on the psychology site? Or for gamification within educational (math) games maybe on the mathematical education page?

Are there relevant sites that I miss? Or is there still a gap and there is not yet a suitable site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is also a [Board and Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) site might be an option, though it seems to be primarily focused on existing games. The help page says that game design questions are on-topic:

> Board and Card Games Stack Exchange is for expert Q&A from people who like playing, discussing the strategy of, and getting rules clarifications of board games, **designing board games** or modifying the rules of existing board games.

The [game-design tag](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design) only has 177 questions, however, so it might not be the best environment for quick answers. Still, the few questions there seem to have answers and high scores, so it might be more of a deficit of game-design questions rather than a deficit of experience.

Comment: In my experience, users are often experts in their own right. For board games, I would not hesitate to ask development questions in a board game forum, as players who are active in such a forum are often highly knowledgeable. A friend of mine is a board game developer working with one of the largest German board game publishers, and they usually develop their games in a process that involves their players/customers. There are many large board game forums on the web, and there is even at least one board game developer forum (which is easy to find through your favourite search engine).

Answer (score 2):

There is a [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com) site. That [allows questions on](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> game design (level design, gameplay, mechanics, etc)

It has a [gamification](/questions/tagged/gamification) [tag](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamification)

**Be careful** though because it is for video or computer games, If you aren't creating video or computer games, your questions would need to be sufficiently generic that they could apply to computer games as well. For instance [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140153/is-there-any-term-for-reverse-gamification) about terminology does seem to have gone down OK even though it doesn't mention computers at all.

Questions asking for references/studies are unlikely to go down well anywhere because we don't really allow questions like that on any site as they tend to attract spam answers.

Comment: Thanks :) I saw that site and it says "Game Development Stack Exchange is for professional and amateur video/computer game developers". Thus I am not sure whether it is the right place for questions concerning non-computer games. But for some of my questions (where it doesn't make a difference whether it is a computer game or not) it seems to be the right place :)

Comment: @simplemind Unfortunately, non-video game mechanics and related questions are **not on topic** on Game Dev. https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/are-board-games-and-game-shows-on-topic/2804#2804